# Property 'locale' does not exist on type 'AppRouterInstance' Error in next 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'  
const { locale } = useRouter();

>! error on locale - Property 'locale' does not exist on type 'AppRouterInstance' Error in next 13
any alternative property?
```

next/router doesn't work as im working in app dir